# How to implement twice function (function that executes other function twice)? Could not match type Record with type Function Int

Tags: purescript

Here is the code

```
module Main where

import Prelude

twice1 f = f . f

transform :: Int -> Int
transform n = n + 1

apply1 x = (twice1 transform) x
```

I have an error

```
  Could not match type

    Record

  with type

    Function Int
```

What's wrong? (you can try code here http://try.purescript.org)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PureScript uses the dot `.` for accessing record fields, as in:

```
r = { a: 42, b: "what?!" }
fourtyTwo = r.a
```

The function composition operator in PureScript is `<<<` (or `>>>` for left-to-right composition), for example:

```
twice1 f = f <<< f
```